Error with Actix Web and Diesel: "the trait Serialize is not implemented for table"
I'm working on a REST API using Actix Web with Diesel and MySQL. I've run into a frustrating issue when trying to return a list of users from the database. Here's my code structure:

I'm using Diesel for database interactions, and my User struct implements Serialize and Deserialize.
In my handler function, I query the users table and attempt to return the result as JSON using HttpResponse::Ok().json(users).

error[E0277]: the trait bound table: "models::users::_::_serde::Serialize" is not satisfied
I’ve made sure that:

My User struct implements Serialize and Deserialize.
I'm using #[diesel(table_name = users)] on my Insertable struct.
My Cargo.toml is configured with the necessary dependencies and features for Diesel and Serde.

Here's the relevant part of my code:
//handler/user.rs
use actix_web::{get, web, HttpResponse, Responder};
use diesel::prelude::*;
use crate::models::{User};
use crate::schema::users::dsl::*;
use crate::DbPool;

#[get("/users")]
async fn get_users(pool: web::Data<DbPool>) -> impl Responder {
    let conn = pool.get().expect("couldn't get db connection from pool");

    let result = web::block(move || users.load::<User>(&conn)).await;

    match result {
        Ok(users) => HttpResponse::Ok().json(users),
        Err(_) => HttpResponse::InternalServerError().finish(),
    }
}

pub fn init_routes(cfg: &mut web::ServiceConfig) {
    cfg.service(get_users);
}


//model/user.rs
use diesel::{prelude::*, MysqlConnection, Queryable, Insertable};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use chrono::NaiveDateTime;
use crate::schema::users;

#[derive(Queryable, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct User {
    pub id: i32,
    pub name: String,
    pub email: String,
    pub password: String,
    pub created_at: Option<NaiveDateTime>,
}

#[derive(Insertable, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[diesel(table_name = users)] 
pub struct UserDTO {
    pub name: String,
    pub email: String,
    pub password: String,
}

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error since the User struct should be serializable. Has anyone faced a similar issue, or could you point out what might be going wrong here?

The error says table: Serialize is not satisfied, which implies that .json(users) is returning the table and not the users retrieved from the table. For starters, try with a different identifier.

So should it return a Vec of Users?

I'm only suggesting changing it to something like Ok(my_users) => HttpResponse::Ok().json(my_users) just as a sanity check.
